# Android GCM (GoogleCloudMessaging) server get state of client

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm a newbie in [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) and I have some questions:

1. How can I get client state from server (client is online or offline)?
2. How can I know my message from server is received or not?

Answer (score 1):

You could send an acknowledgement from your client to your server when the client receives a message (using your own HTTP connection to your server). If you include some message identifier in your GCM message, the acknowledgement can contain that identifier, letting the server know exactly which message was acknowledged.